# Backbone multi-collection global search

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm playing around with the idea of creating a global search that allows me to find any model in any of a number of collections by any of the model's attributes. For example:

I have the following collections:

- Users
- Applications
- Roles

I don't know ahead of time what attributes each User, Applicaion and Role will have but for illustration purposes lets say I have:

- User.name
- User.last_name
- User.email
- Application.title
- Application.description
- Role.name
- Role.description

Now, lets say I create a model called `Site` with a method called `search`. I want `Site.search(term)` to search through all the items in each collection where `term` matches any of the attributes. In essence, a global model search.

How would you suggest I approach this? I can brute-force it by iterating through all the collections' models and each model's attributes but that seems bloated and inefficient.

Any suggestions?

/// A few minutes later...

Here's a bit of code I tried just now:

```
find: function(query) {
    var results = {}; // variable to hold the results
    // iterate over the collections
    _.each(["users", "applications", "roles"], _.bind(function(collection){
        // I want the result to be grouped by type of model so I add arrays to the results object
        if ( !_.isUndefined(results[collection]) || !_.isArray(results[collection]) ) {
            results[collection] = [];
        }
        // iterate over the collection's models
        _.each(this.get(collection).models, function(model){
            // iterate over each model's attributes
            _.each(model.attributes, function(value){
                // for now I'm only considering string searches
                if (_.isString(value)) {
                    // see if `query` is in the attribute's string/value
                    if (value.indexOf(query) > -1) {
                        // if so, push it into the result's collection arrray
                        results[collection].push(model);
                    }
                };
            });
        });
        // a little cleanup
        results[collection] = _.compact(results[collection]);
        // remove empty arrays
        if (results[collection].length < 1) {
            delete results[collection];
        }
    },this));
    // return the results
    return results;
}
```

This yields the expected result and I suppose it works fine but it bothers me that I'm iterating over three arrays. there may not be another solution but I have a feeling there is. If anyone can suggest one, thank you! Meanwhile I'll keep researching.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly discourage you from doing this, unless you have a very limited set of data and performance is not really a problem for you.

Iteration over everything is a no-no if you want to perform search. Search engines index data and make the process feasible. It is hard to build search, and there is no client-side library that does that effectively.

Which is why everybody is doing searching on the server. There exist easy (or sort of) to use search engines such as [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or the more recent and my personal preference [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Presumably you already store your models/collections on the server, it should be trivial to also index them. Then searching becomes a question of making a REST call from your client.

Comment: We've had success with [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) as well, pretty easy to get going.